# ¿Hacer funcionar un required? HTML5

Tags: html5, required

chicos! Seré breve, estoy haciendo un formulario básico en HTML del tipo "Regístrese aquí", algunos input los tiro con atributo 'required', pero al probarlo no me funcionan. Dejo ejemplo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
<title>Regístrese aquí</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Registrar.php" class="formulario">
    <h1 class="titulo">Regístrese Aquí</h1>
    <div>
        <label for="nombres">Nombres: </label>
        <input type="text" name="nombres" id="nombres" required>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="apellidos">Apellidos: </label>
        <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" >
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="correo">Correo: </label>
        <input type="email" name="correo" id="correo" required>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="estadoCivil">Estado Civil</label>
        <select name="estadoCivil" id="estadoCivil">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="1">Soltero(a)</option>
            <option value="2">Casado(a)</option>
            <option value="3">Union Libre</option>
            <option value="4">Viudo(a)</option>             
        </select>
    </div>      

    <div>
        <label for="genero">Genero: </label>
        Hombre <input type="radio" name="genero value="H> 
        Mujer <input type="radio" name="genero value="M>    
    </div>          

    <div>
        <label for="password">Password: </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="password1">Confirmar Password: </label>
        <input type="password1" name="password1" id="password1" required>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Enviar" id="enviar" class="boton">
        <input type="reset" class="boton">
    </div>  

    <div class="mensajes">

    </div>  
</form>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript para el type button

```
enviar=document.getElementById("enviar");
enviar.onclick=validarDatos;

function validarDatos () {
    var elemento =document.getElementById("correo");
    if (elemento.checkValidity() ==false && elemento.required){
    //document.getElementById("mensajes").innerHTML=`<p>Debe ingresar un ${elemento.id} valido</p>`;
    document.getElementById("mensajes").innerHTML="<p>Debe ingresar un "+elemento.id +" valido</p>";
}
}
```

Comment: cual es el error?

Comment: cual es el comportamiento esperado?

Comment: yo diria que pongas todo el html del formulario

Comment: @ShadowPaz, lo sucedido es que al visualizarlo, no pasa nada con el required.

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez, ya lo pongo

Comment: ya encontre cual es el detalle si gustas checar mi respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un par de cosas a mencionar, si lo único que buscas es que no deje proceder un envío si el campo esta vacío la sintaxis que usas es la correcta:

```
<input type="text" id="nombre-de-usuario" name="usuario" required>
```

Sin embargo lo que sí tienes que considerar es el grado de compatibilidad con los navegadores lo cual puedes checar en el siguiente enlace oficial:

[Required en CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=required)

Donde puedes observar que el único problema que pudieras tener es si usas Internet Explorer desde su versión 10 hacia abajo

**También te comento que no funciona porque haces uso de la etiqueta button para hacer el procesamiento del formulario el cual por defecto solo funcionará si lo vinculas con alguna acción de JavaScript. Si quieres ver que si sirve solo cambia el type de button a submit**

Mira así:

```
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="enviar" class="boton">
```

Te comento también que para hacer una validación mas simple, deja el atributo required en el HTML así cuando este disponible también funcionará y por otro lado en el JavaScript puedes manejarlo así:

En el input botón invocas a la función así:

```
<div>
        <input onclick="validar()" type="button" value="Enviar" id="enviar" class="boton">
        <input type="reset" class="boton">
    </div>
```

Y dentro del JavaScript manéjalo así:

```
<script>
    function validar() {
        var elemento = document.getElementById("correo").value
      if (elemento == ""){
        alert("Debes llenar el campo")
        return false
      }else {
        alert("Genial el valor es: "+elemento)
        return false
      }
    }

  </script>
```

> Y con lo anterior puedes dejar tu input como button sin necesidad de
> ponerle submit

Comment: Pero sí tengo una acción de JS 
    
    enviar=document.getElementById("enviar");
    enviar.onclick=validarDatos;

function validarDatos () {
    var elemento =document.getElementById("correo");
    if (elemento.checkValidity() ==false && elemento.required){
    //document.getElementById("mensajes").innerHTML=`<p>Debe ingresar un ${elemento.id} valido</p>`;
    document.getElementById("mensajes").innerHTML="<p>Debe ingresar un "+elemento.id +" valido</p>";
}
}

Me disculparás, no sé cómo agregar código en un comentario

Comment: yas mismo anexo el código corregido a mi respyuesta espera

Comment: listo mira lo que agregue a mi respuesta

Comment: Shadow, muchas gracias! Disculpa la demora

Comment: no hay problema cuando tengas otra cuestión no dudes en postearla

Comment: Funciona perfecto, pero tengo una duda ...si al validar los datos existe alguna forma de re-direccional a una pagina, creo que eso es en el script, pero no tengo de como hacerlo, aquí dejo mi ejemplo, funciona el código, valida los campos pero no me lleva a la pagina que le asigno en windows.open
```
<script>
function myFunction() { var elemento = document.getElementById("correo").value if (elemento == ""){ alert("Debes llenar el campo") return false }else { alert("Genial el valor es: window.open("/pre/form.html");"+elemento) return false }
}
</script>
```